# Item level permission on Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, item-level-permissions

I want to store multiple videos to my share point. In my CRM i have tickets and these videos are assigned to specific tickets. 
If user have permission to that site he can view the video else not.

I dont want to create multiple sites based on user roles to solve this issue.

I want to assign permission for user directly on the item so that only the user have access to the video item can play the file others not.

Also, Is there any SDK available for doing this programatically?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

To assign permission for user directly on the item so that only the user have access to the video item can play the file others not, you can set unique permissions on the item.

Chose an item->Shared with->Advanced:

[image]

Stop Inheriting Permissions, then you can grant unique permissions for the item:
[image]